# Draw table with row and column count given with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Let's say I have defined the following variables in my controller:
$scope.rows, $scope.columns

I should draw a table in my html file, that has $scope.rows amount of rows and $scope.columns amount of columns.
(Later they will be coloured with jQuery...)

Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas" what? Show us what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="columnin columns"></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat ="row in rows"></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In your Controller:

```
$scope.columns = new Array(10);
$scope.rows = new Array(10);
```

The you could also do this in a function like :

```
$scope.setSizeOf(column, rows){
$scope.columns = new Array(column);
    $scope.rows = new Array(rows);
}
```